How do I pass a base 64 image to Roboflow's Infer API endpoint?
In the documentation for the API, it says to pass base64 images through the body of our POST request.
response = requests.post(roboflow_url, params=params, data=base64_image)

This is the request code and all it returns is error code 400. params is my API key. What do I do?
Documentation link : https://docs.roboflow.com/deploy/hosted-api/custom-models/object-detection

Hi, 400 means bad request. It means the request was not properly formatted to be understood by the server. As you said, in params you should include the image. To help you, you need to add more details, like what language your're using (as roboflow supports many in their examples page) and maybe an image of the specific error you're seeing. Errors usually come with messages along with the status code.

@DanielCruz I'm using Python for this request. Are you sure I have to include the image in params? Because the documentation specifically says to pass the base64 image through the request body, which is why I used 'data=base64_image' in order to pass it through the body of the request. params is where I keep the API key to pass through the request parameters.

Can you share the minimal reproducible example? It will be easier to provide help if we can see what you already tried.

Check how it's done in Roboflow inference
Here you can see how image is decomposed to bytes
Here you can see how image is serialized
Based on above two you can write your own image serializer which >>should work<<
import base64
import json

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


cv_image = cv.imread("/path/to/image.jpg", cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
_, img_encoded = cv.imencode(".jpg", cv_image)

image = {
    "type": "base64",
    "value": base64.b64encode(np.array(img_encoded).tobytes()).decode(),
}

You can try to plug this into your code.
You can also use inference_sdk
import base64

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

from inference.core.utils.image_utils import load_image_from_encoded_bytes
from inference_sdk import InferenceHTTPClient
from inference_sdk.http.entities import InferenceConfiguration

client = InferenceHTTPClient(
    api_url="http://localhost:9001",  # you can spin up local instance
    api_key="...",
)

client.use_configuration(InferenceConfiguration(visualize_predictions=True, visualize_labels=True))
client.configure(InferenceConfiguration(visualize_predictions=True, visualize_labels=True))

with client.use_model(model_id="yolov8n-640"):
    predictions = client.infer("/path/to/image.jpg")

b64_encoded_img = predictions.get("visualization")
blob = base64.b64decode(b64_encoded_img)
np_array = np.frombuffer(blob, dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv.imdecode(np_array, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv.imshow("", img)
cv.waitKey(0)

(Above can be found here)
